# Am I causing a retain cycle?

Tags: objective-c

This is essentially what I am doing in my code, not sure whether triggering the block of a strong-referenced property causes a retain cycle. Any insight?

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, weak) id object1;  
@property(nonatomic) id object2;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)myMethod
{  
    [self.object2 performBlock:^{  
        [self.object1 performSelector:@selector(mySelector)];
    }];  
}

@end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MyClass** keeps a strong reference to **object2** and within the block that you pass to **object2** *performBlock* your are keeping a strong reference to self (**MyClass** instance).

Is **object2** keeping a strong reference to this block? If so then yes, you'll get a retained cycle. However if the block is called within the scope of the *performBlock* method and then discarded (not stored by object2) you won't have an issue.

If you're not sure you can play safe and pass a weak reference to self in the block:

```
__typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
[self.object2 performBlock:^{  
    [weakSelf.object1 performSelector:@selector(mySelector)];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks! No, `performBlock` does not keep a reference to its block parameter, so it looks like I'm in the clear as is.

Answer (score 2):

Since we don't know the class of `object2`, we don't know what its `performBlock` method actually does. However, it sounds like it probably runs the block immediately and doesn't store a strong reference to it persistently.

If that is the case, then there is no retain cycle.